# Why does Python's itertools.cycle need to create a copy of the iterable?

Tags: python, iterator, cycle, python-itertools

The documentation for Python's itertools.cycle() gives a pseudo-code implementation as:

```
def cycle(iterable):
    # cycle('ABCD') --> A B C D A B C D A B C D ...
    saved = []
    for element in iterable:
        yield element
        saved.append(element)
    while saved:
        for element in saved:
              yield element
```

Below, it states: "Note, this member of the toolkit may require significant auxiliary storage (depending on the length of the iterable)."

I basically was going down this path, except I did this, which does not require creating a copy of the iterable:

```
def loop(iterable):
    it = iterable.__iter__()

    while True:
        try:
            yield it.next()
        except StopIteration:
            it = iterable.__iter__()
            yield it.next()

x = {1, 2, 3}

hard_limit = 6
for i in loop(x):
    if hard_limit <= 0:
        break

    print i
    hard_limit -= 1
```

prints:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Yes, I realize my implementation wouldn't work for str's, but it could be made to. I'm more curious as to why it creates another copy. I have a feeling it has to do with garbage collection, but I'm not well studied in this area of Python.

Thanks!

Comment: @Martijn how did you add syntax highlighting? I couldn't figure out how to do that...

Comment: I didn't; I added the `python` tag and then highlighting is applied automatically. But even without the tag highlighting is often accurately guessed anyway.

Comment: Ahhh, but the python2.7 tag doesn't? weird...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Iterables can only be iterated over *once*.

You create a *new* iterable in your loop instead. Cycle cannot do that, it has to work with whatever you passed in. `cycle` cannot simply recreate the iterable. It thus is forced to store all the elements the original iterable produces.

If you were to pass in the following generator instead, your `loop()` fails:

```
def finite_generator(source=[3, 2, 1]):
    while source:
        yield source.pop()
```

Now your `loop()` produces:

```
>>> hard_limit = 6
>>> for i in loop(finite_generator()):
...     if hard_limit <= 0:
...         break
...     print i
...     hard_limit -= 1
... 
1
2
3
```

Your code would only work for sequences, for which using `cycle()` would be overkill; you don't need the storage burden of `cycle()` in that case. Simplify it down to:

```
def loop_sequence(seq):
    while True:
        for elem in seq:
            yield elem
```