# In Python, why does itertools.cycle require additional memory?

Tags: python, cycle, python-itertools

I'm curious about the warning in [itertools.cycle(iterable)](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) :

> Make an iterator returning elements from the
>   iterable and saving a copy of each. When the iterable is exhausted,
>   return elements from the saved copy. Repeats indefinitely.
>
> Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def cycle(iterable):
>     # cycle('ABCD') --> A B C D A B C D A B C D ...
>     saved = []
>     for element in iterable:
>         yield element
>         saved.append(element)
>     while saved:
>         for element in saved:
>               yield element
> ```

The entry also contains the warning, "Note, this member of the toolkit may require significant auxiliary storage (depending on the length of the iterable)."

Couldn't you avoid the additional storage requirement (and some complexity) with:

```
def cycle(iterable):
    while True:
        for i in iterable:
            yield i
```

What's the advantage of storing used items in `saved`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some iterables can only be iterated once. Thus cycle will store a copy so it can continue to read those items.
See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638639/why-does-pythons-itertools-cycle-need-to-create-a-copy-of-the-iterable).

Comment: ‘Some iterables can only be iterated once.’ Yes, those are called iterators.

Answer (score 0):

The iterable could be some generator that does expensive calculations to generate the element.

By caching the results of the iterable, you don't have to repeat what could be a potentially expensive and time-consuming operation to cycle through the iterable.